# How to calculate a score/indicator in R?

Tags: r

I want to try calculate a score or create an index that gives the degree of states "marginalization" within a world economy. In other words, an index that would indicate state's position within the world economy.

Basically, I try to replicate someone else's indicator. He defined "marginalization" within the World Economy as a function of that country's percentage of world trade.

It was computed by calculating: the total imports + total exports of a given nation divided by the total imports + exports of the world economy. The inverse of that divided by 100.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate this in R, using my data. Below I give an (real) example.

```
Country  Year     EXPORT(%GDP)  IMPORT(%GDP)   GDP(current$) 
A        2001        22,14        21,96            3,78(+11)                    
B        2001        35,43        31,80            5387293(..)
C        2001        27,22        30,84            1,90
WORLD    2001        24,43        24,20            3,30(+13)
```

To be clear, I want to calculate a score for each country and year in my data (**about 150 countries, from 1990 to 2014**). The equation is (to be clear, again):  import + export (for a given country in the dataset)  / import + export (of the world economy, please see the variable "WORLD" in the example.

EDIT: another example with current $ (if this is of any help)

```
Country  Year     EXPORT(current$)  IMPORT(c$)          GDP(c$) 
    A        2001        8,38177(..)   8,31506           3,78(+11)                    
    B        2001        1,90875(..)   1,71328           5,387293(..)
    C        2001        5,1872(..)    5,87710           1,90
    WORLD    2001        7,6811(..)    7,7101            3,30(+13)
```

Comment: There is a modelling issue: the figures in Export and Import makes no sense with your calculation. Exp. and Imp. are defined as percentage of GDP for each country: you must mention this GDP in a fifth column to calculate the raw value of import and export. From these raw values, we can apply your formula (but we can't apply it with percentage!)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thanks – make sense. I do also have raw values  for EXP/IMP (Exp/Imp of goods and services current $). I have now added the GDP into inte data frame. How can I do the calculation in R?

Comment: I'm still unable to make sense of the data for the purposes you propose. The totals of countries A,B, abd C are much more than the values for WORLD.

Comment: @BondedDust I was thinking about it as well. The data is well used and comes from the World Bank (World Development Indicators). Not sure how they computed it. But it make sense that some of the countries are outliers with big/small export/import values. This is just a sample of my data. Not sure if the real values are important for the R-code? It is a pain to do this calculation in Excel, that is for sure.

Comment: There is something you have not told us about that data.

Comment: @BondedDust I have a country-year data that looks just like the example I provided. Please, let me know what more you would like me to tell about it.

Comment: I would like the total to be be at least as large as the sum of the individual items!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the good old data.table:

```
library( data.table)

# Thanks "TheKevinNeville" for the sample data!
country <- c("A", "B", "C", "World")
year <- c(rep(2001, 4), rep(2002, 4))
export <- abs(rnorm(8) * 5)
import <- abs(rnorm(8) * 5)
dt <- data.table( country,year,export,import)

# Here you calculate the index (rank) per group
dt[,index := (import + export) / .SD[country=="World", import + export],by=.(year)]
```

The result looks like this:

```
   country year   export    import    index
1:       A 2001 4.641794 7.3788739 6.222089
2:       B 2001 4.286842 1.3656420 2.925816
3:       C 2001 1.919439 1.1210429 1.573802
4:   World 2001 1.164199 0.7677355 1.000000
5:       A 2002 1.303430 3.5848178 1.478056
6:       B 2002 4.231528 2.6427575 2.078573
7:       C 2002 8.655763 7.1272979 4.772314
8:   World 2002 2.134707 1.1725057 1.000000
```

And if you want to order the results per year and index (descending) you could add the following code:

```
# setorder reorders the rows of a data.table by reference,
# based on the columns provided. 
setorder(dt, year, -index)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I am going to accept this answer soon – I have a minor problem applying it though. I got this errror: 




Error in `[.data.frame`(score, , `:=`(index, (imp + exp)/.SD[country ==  : 
  unused argument (by = .(year))





Why (by=.(year))  is unused argument? I have a year variable in the dataset (1989 to 2014), called "year".

Comment: Can you please post the complete line of code you are using? I guess you are using a data.frame instead of a data.table! Try to convert your data.frame into a data.table using "dt <- setDT( your.data.frame )".

Comment: You're right, I am using a data.frame.. 
Therefore I tried this: "mydataYY <- data.table(mydata$country, mydata$year, mydata$imp, mydata$exp )".    I got this: "Error: could not find function "data.table" .    I tried also your suggestion "dt <- setDT( your.data.frame )" but it says that it cannot find function "setDT". Am I missing some R-package here?

Comment: The original code that generated the Error was: mydata[,index := (imp + exp) / .SD[country=="World", imp + exp],by=.(year)]. Where "mediate" is a data frame.

Comment: (I am sorry for so many comments..) Now I did covert it to a data.table (data.table package). However, this the error I got this time =====> Error in `[.data.table`(score1, , `:=`(index, (imp + exp)/.SD[country ==  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type closure. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]

Comment: Requires steps to solve your problems:
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(mydata)
# Then the code of my answer

If it doesn't work: Post "names(mydata)" as comment please

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was that export and import was factors..I fixed it.. and your code does its job!

Answer (score -1):

Creating data.

```
country <- c("A", "B", "C", "World")
year <- c(rep(2001, 4), rep(2002, 4))
export <- abs(rnorm(8) * 5)
import <- abs(rnorm(8) * 5)

mydf <- data.frame(country=country,Year=year,EXPORT=export, IMPORT=import)
```

For loop.

```
mydf$Score <- NA
for(i in 2001:2002){
index <- mydf[,"Year"] == i
current_world <- mydf$country[index] == "World"
mydf$Score[index] <- (mydf$EXPORT[index] + mydf$IMPORT[index]) / (mydf$EXPORT[index][current_world] + mydf$IMPORT[index][current_world])
}
```

Comment: No, no and no for loop. This is not an R answer.

Comment: This is indeed R code. If you dont want a for-loop you could probably use lapply.

Comment: providing this kind of answer gives extreme bad coding habits in R ...use instead aggregate/data.table/dplyr but clearly not this.